# How to compare and move other size in assembly 8 bit and 16 bit

Tags: assembly

Code:

```
   AX=2013
    AL=AH+1
    if (BX<AL) then
    BX=AL
    BL=BH*3-AH
    end if
```

Anyone can convert this code to assembly?

Comment: Have you tried writing it in a programming language (e.g. C, C++) and then using a compiler to assemble it? (e.g. `g++ -S output_file.s input_file.c` will create a file with raw assembly.)

Answer (score 0):

Due to your question's title, I assume this is the part that is causing you problems:

```
if (BX<AL) then
    BX=AL
```

First, you need to be clear about whether you have unsigned or signed values. Then, you can zero or sign-extend your 8 bit register to an available 16 bit one, and perform your comparison and assignment using that. Such as for unsigned:

```
    movzx cx, al ; zero extend to 16 bits
    cmp bx, cx
    jae skip     ; unsigned condition
    mov bx, cx
skip:
```

Or signed:

```
    movsx cx, al ; sign extend to 16 bit
    cmp bx, cx
    jge skip     ; signed condition
    mov bx, cx
skip:
```

If you are not allowed to use another register, you can build the comparison from the 8 bit halves manually. Unsigned example:

```
    test bh, bh
    jnz skip     ; if bh != 0 then bx > al
    cmp bl, al
    jae skip
    movzx bx, al
skip:
```

If `movzx` is not available (it is a 386+ instruction) you can emulate that by zeroing the top 8 bits, such as:

```
    test bh, bh
    jnz skip     ; if bh != 0 then bx > al
    cmp bl, al
    jae skip
    xor bh, bh
    mov bl, al
skip:
```

For signed it is more complicated, left as an exercise :-)

Comment: i have tried above code before asking here, but happened error 'wrong systax'

Comment: Well, you didn't specify what assembler you use, so it's your fault. Anyway, the above should work in any intel syntax assembler, I have tested in `nasm`. Next time if you have code you already tried, be sure to post that in the question, and include exact error message.

Comment: `movsx` and `movzx` are 386+ instructions maybe you need to enable that. If not available, I edited the answer to include a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the different sizes, like **cmp bx,al**, there are two options:

```
mov ah, 0                                      
cmp bx, ax                                     cmp bl, al
```

In both cases we have to lose something. In the left code we lose AH, in the right code ignore BH.

Next is a little program for your algorithm (made with EMU8086):

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

a_h db ?

.code
start:

;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;LAO TA.
  mov  ax, 2013   ;AX = 2013.
  mov  al, ah     ;AL = AH.
  inc  al         ;AL + 1.
  mov  a_h, ah    ;PRESERVE AH FOR LATER, BECAUSE WE WILL LOSE IT.

  mov  bx, 7      ;WE NEED A VALUE THAT WILL TAKE US TO THE "THEN".
;IF ( BX < AL ).        
  mov  ah, 0      ;CLEAR AH TO USE AX (YOU SEE, WE JUST LOST AH).
  cmp  bx, ax     ;CMP BX, AL (BECAUSE AH=0).
  jae  not_less   ;IF ( BX >= AX ) JUMP TO NOT_LESS.
;THEN (EXECUTES IF BX < AX).
  mov  bx, ax     ;BX = AL (BECAUSE AH=0).
;BH * 3.
  mov  al, 3      ;NECESSARY FOR MUL.
  mul  bh         ;BH * AL. RESULT = AX.
  mov  bh, al     ;ASSUME RESULT FITS IN AL (RESULT <= 255).
;BH*3 - AH.  
  sub  bh, a_h    ;THIS IS THE AH WE PRESERVED BEFORE.
;BL = (BH*3 - AH).
  mov  bl, bh
;END IF.

not_less:

;WAIT FOR ANY KEY.    
  mov  ah, 7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

end start
```

Next is the test data, notice I had to assign an appropiate value for BX to enter the IF:

```
AX = 2013 ------------> AX = 7DDh (AL=DD, AH=7).
AL = AH + 1 ----------> AL = 7+1 = 8.
BX = 7 ---------------> WE NEED A VALUE THAT WILL TAKE US TO THE "THEN".
if (BX < AL) then ----> IF ( 7 < 8 ).
  BX = AL ------------> BX = 8 (BL=8, BH=0).
  BL = BH * 3 - AH ---> BL = (0 * 3 - 7) = -7.
end if
```

It's important to mention that, when working with BX and AL, we are losing BH. To prevent this, we may work with BL and AL or BH and AL.

Another thing, I preserved the original AH at the beginning (7) because we lose it twice: under the IF (to compare BX with AL, AH was cleared before) and in the MUL (because the result takes whole AX). It's not necessary to preserve AH, but this will change the final result:

```
AX = 2013 ------------> AX = 7DDh (AL=DD, AH=7).
AL = AH + 1 ----------> AL = 7+1 = 8.
BX = 7 ---------------> WE NEED A VALUE THAT WILL TAKE US TO THE "THEN".
if (BX < AL) then ----> IF ( 7 < 8 ).
  BX = AL ------------> BX = 8 (BL=8, BH=0).
  BL = BH * 3 - AH ---> BL = (0 * 3 - 0) = 0.
end if
```

This new result is because BH * 3 leaves the result in AX, and 0 * 3 = 0. This is why I chose to preserve the original value of AH.